# изменить соответствующее значение столбца mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Всем привет.
Есть таблицы
products(id,id_product,code..) и product_prices(id,id_product,price..)
мне нужно зная только значение code изменить соответствующее значение price.

Вот что написал я но что то не работает

```
UPDATE product_prices
SET product_prices.price = 1170
WHERE (
    SELECT product_prices.price, products.code
    FROM  product_prices INNER JOIN  products ON
products.id_product=product_prices.id_product
        WHERE code = 37432
    );
```

Comment: Хотите ли вы поменять все цены продукта, если их несколько, или только какую-то одну? Это важно.

Comment: Да замена всех цен, но мне достаточно разобраться остальное я сделаю. Спасибо огромное за помощь

Comment: Данная таблица взята с virtuemarta joomla,

Answer (score 2):

Запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
UPDATE product_prices
SET price = ...
WHERE id_product IN
    (SELECT id_product
    FROM products
    WHERE code = ...)
```

Только вместо ... подставьте свои значения

Comment: error :  operand should contain 1 column

Comment: @DJK, вообще-то запрос от Tema_Bel выглядит рабочим. Меня только смущает, что должны измениться все цены выбранного продукта. Если бы вы привели код create table и несколько тестовых записей, было бы проще. sqldiffle.com вам в помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Тут необходимо уточнить как связаны таблицы `products` и `product_prices` и надо ли менять *все* цены продукта.
Я исхожу из того, что таблицы относятся как один-ко-многим, а менять надо только *последнюю цену*, то есть запись с наибольшим id. Мне это кажется логичным.

```
UPDATE
  product_prices AS pc JOIN
  (
    SELECT id_product, MAX(id) AS id 
    FROM product_prices 
    GROUP BY id_product
  ) AS pclast USING (id_product, id) JOIN
  products AS p USING (id_product)
SET
  pc.price = 1170
WHERE
  p.code = 'GAMA666'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cda20/2